# Solve with real positive parametrs in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, solver

I would like to solve for eta in Mathematica

Solve[-Sqrt[1-(a eta b )]+Sqrt[1-(a eta c)]-(1-eta) n g + (1-eta) ns P == 0,eta]

with all parameters being Reals and positive and eta Reals and positive

How to include these assumptions ?

Comment: Since you only have two square roots and everything else is positive you can push everything but the square roots to the RHS, square both sides, push everything but the Sqrt[]Sqrt[] to the right hand side, square both sides, expand, Collect on eta, Reduce that for eta, Simplify with the assumption a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && n > 0 && g > 0 && ns > 0 && P > 0 && eta > 0 and you end up with four Root[] of a quartic equation in eta. If you REALLY want it you can use ToRadicals on that and get a stunningly large solution for eta.

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new at mathematica and my question is more how to write it and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, usually for simpler problems, you could just enter something like

```
Reduce[-Sqrt[1-(a eta b)]+Sqrt[1-(a eta c)]-(1-eta)n g+(1-eta)ns P==0 &&
  a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && n>0 && g>0 && ns>0 && P>0 && eta>0, eta]
```

and wait and hope that it finishes. That didn't finish for me in the amount of time that I was willing to wait and so I used a different approach.

Note: I have intentionally left the few In[] and Out[] in this so that you can see exactly where I was using Mathematica to do a step. All the other lines I was doing manually.

For any problem there are at least a dozen different ways of doing it in Mathematica. I did it this way to quickly get you an answer when you might otherwise wait minutes or hours and never see your result automatically calculated.

```
-Sqrt[1-(a eta b)]+Sqrt[1-(a eta c)]-(1-eta)n g+(1-eta)ns P==0

-Sqrt[1-(a eta b)]+Sqrt[1-(a eta c)]==(1-eta)n g-(1-eta)ns P

In[1]:=Expand[(-Sqrt[1-(a eta b)]+Sqrt[1-(a eta c)])^2]==((1-eta)n g-(1-eta)ns P)^2

Out[1]=2-a b eta-a c eta-2 Sqrt[1-a b eta]Sqrt[1-a c eta]==((1-eta)g n-(1-eta)ns P)^2

-2 Sqrt[1-a b eta]Sqrt[1-a c eta]==((1-eta)g n-(1-eta)ns P)^2-(2-a b eta-a c eta)

(-2 Sqrt[1-a b eta]Sqrt[1-a c eta])^2==(((1-eta)g n-(1-eta)ns P)^2-(2-a b eta-a c eta))^2

4(1-a b eta)(1-a c eta)==(((1-eta)g n-(1-eta)ns P)^2-(2-a b eta-a c eta))^2

In[2]:= Simplify[Reduce[4(1-a b eta)(1-a c eta)==(((1-eta)g n-(1-eta)ns P)^2-
  (2-a b eta-a c eta))^2,eta],a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && n>0 && g>0 && ns>0 && P>0 && eta>0]

Out[2]= (b==c || g n!=ns P) && (
eta == Root[-4 g^2 n^2+g^4 n^4+8 g n ns P-4 g^3 n^3 ns P-4 ns^2 P^2+
 6 g^2 n^2 ns^2 P^2-4 g n ns^3 P^3+ns^4 P^4+(8 g^2 n^2+2 a b g^2 n^2+
 2 a c g^2 n^2-4 g^4 n^4-16 g n ns P-4 a b g n ns P-4 a c g n ns P+
 16 g^3 n^3 ns P+8 ns^2 P^2+2 a b ns^2 P^2+2 a c ns^2 P^2-
 24 g^2 n^2 ns^2 P^2+16 g n ns^3 P^3-4 ns^4 P^4) #1+(a^2 b^2-2 a^2 b c+
 a^2 c^2-4 g^2 n^2-4 a b g^2 n^2-4 a c g^2 n^2+6 g^4 n^4+8 g n ns P+
 8 a b g n ns P+8 a c g n ns P-24 g^3 n^3 ns P-4 ns^2 P^2-4 a b ns^2 P^2-
 4 a c ns^2 P^2+36 g^2 n^2 ns^2 P^2-24 g n ns^3 P^3+6 ns^4 P^4) #1^2+
 (2 a b g^2 n^2+2 a c g^2 n^2-4 g^4 n^4-4 a b g n ns P-4 a c g n ns P+
 16 g^3 n^3 ns P+2 a b ns^2 P^2+2 a c ns^2 P^2-24 g^2 n^2 ns^2 P^2+
 16 g n ns^3 P^3-4 ns^4 P^4) #1^3+(g^4 n^4-4 g^3 n^3 ns P+
 6 g^2 n^2 ns^2 P^2-4 g n ns^3 P^3+ns^4 P^4) #1^4 &,1] ||
eta == Root[...more...&,2] ||
eta == Root[...more...&,3] ||
eta == Root[...more...&,4] ||
g n == ns P)

In[3]:= ToRadicals[eta == Root[...same...&,1]]

Out[3]= eta==...aTrulyHugeResultForTheFirstOfFourRoots...
```

Try to check all this carefully and understand how it was done